# Dúvida simples sobre laço for

Tags: javascript, jquery, loop, for

Tenho 4 imagens: uma imagem sobre a outra dentro de uma `div`. Está uma sobre a outra porque está em posição `absolute`. Gostaria de fazer um *slideshow* simples, apenas para aprender o seu funcionamento básico dentro de um *loop*. O que está errado no código abaixo?

(Nota: O código todo está disponível [aqui](http://codepen.io/colombe/pen/KMpjMX))

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    for ($n = 0; $n < 3; $n++) {
        $('img:eq($n)').fadeToggle().delay(3000).fadeToggle();
    }      
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu creio que não está à procura de um loop, mas sim de um setInterval:

```js
$('.item:gt(0)').hide(); // esconder todos os items cujo index é maior que 0, só o primeiro fica visível
var countItems = $('.item').length; // num de .item que temos
var next;
var slide = setInterval(function() {
    next = $('.item:visible').index() + 1; // ver qual é o item que está visivél, saber o seu index e somar um, que vai ser o proximo .item a aparecer
    if(next >= countItems) { // caso o next seja maior ou igual do que o numero total de .item
     next = 0; // o proximo .item a aparecer vai ser o primeiro, cujo index é 0
    }
    $('.item').fadeOut();
    $('.item:eq(' +next+ ')').fadeIn(); // aparecer o proximo .item, definido pela var next
}, 1500); // definir tempo entre cada slide
```

```css
.item {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="marco">
  <div class="item" style="background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5UmFIcqYO9w/hqdefault.jpg)">
  
  </div>
  <div class="item" style="background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mi6Yb_HPS9A/hqdefault.jpg)">
  
  </div>
  <div class="item" style="background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0MyTHD24HKs/hqdefault.jpg)">
  
  </div>
  <div class="item" style="background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hQTsb64ZuFo/hqdefault.jpg)">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

EXEMPLO no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smt03ejz/6/), desta maneira todos vão ter as mesmas dimensões, basta ajustar o comprimento (width) e altura (height) que quer em `.item`

Comment: Olha! Valeu! Isso me deu uma nova maneira de pensar meus códigos! Realmente funciona melhor!